# How to create a hyperlink in excel cell via ms graph API?

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to create a hyperlink in excel cell via ms graph API. Is there a way to do that?

for example the cell text is 'http://stackoverflow.com', and I want to make it [link](https://stackoverflow.com)

When attempted to set the cell text to a html tag, it display just that!
Please help

Comment: Unfortunately the feature is not available using Microsoft Graph APIs at this point. I remember [two of the user voice's filed](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/filters/top?category_id=359629&query=hyperlink) for it and you can see the response from Graph API team as well on it. Please go ahead and upvote it, so that Excel Graph API team can consider implementing it.

Comment: Let me know if you need any help or the above is useful.

Comment: Thank you Dev for your response.

Comment: Glad to know that it had helped. Moving this to answer. Consider upvoting it. So it can be useful to other community members and they can upvote too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the feature is not available using Microsoft Graph APIs at this point - this is "by design". Being said that i remember [two of the user voice's filed](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/filters/top?category_id=359629&query=hyperlink) for it; also you can see the response from Graph API team as well on it. Please go ahead and upvote it, so that Excel Graph API team can consider implementing it.